# How to get the notification background color after android N

Tags: android, colors, notifications, background

I want to define the Notification UI，because in some phones the notification background color is white, and in other phones is dark. I  want to check what is the background color so to choose a different layout.

Before android N, my code was like this class:

https://github.com/lizixian18/MusicLibrary/blob/master/musiclibrary/src/main/java/com/lzx/musiclibrary/notification/NotificationColorUtils.java#isDarkNotificationBar

The principle is to check the default `contentView` title and content `TextView` color. But after android N the default `contentView` is `null`.

Notification#build:

```
public Notification build() {

    if (mContext.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.N
            && (useExistingRemoteView())) {
        if (mN.contentView == null) {
            mN.contentView = createContentView();
            mN.extras.putInt(EXTRA_REBUILD_CONTENT_VIEW_ACTION_COUNT,
                    mN.contentView.getSequenceNumber());
        }
        if (mN.bigContentView == null) {
            mN.bigContentView = createBigContentView();
            if (mN.bigContentView != null) {
                mN.extras.putInt(EXTRA_REBUILD_BIG_CONTENT_VIEW_ACTION_COUNT,
                        mN.bigContentView.getSequenceNumber());
            }
        }
        if (mN.headsUpContentView == null) {
            mN.headsUpContentView = createHeadsUpContentView();
            if (mN.headsUpContentView != null) {
                mN.extras.putInt(EXTRA_REBUILD_HEADS_UP_CONTENT_VIEW_ACTION_COUNT,
                        mN.headsUpContentView.getSequenceNumber());
            }
        }
    }

    if ((mN.defaults & DEFAULT_LIGHTS) != 0) {
        mN.flags |= FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    }
    return mN;
}
```

So my question is: How to check whether the notification background color  is dark or white after Android N?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the default background color so you can set the color on your text?

Comment: yes ,you are right

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** recommended to set custom colors on the text of your notification. Instead, you should use the [TextAppearance.Compat.Notification styles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/R.style.html) for your text:

- `TextAppearance.Compat.Notification` for regular text in your notification
- `TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title` for the title style
- `TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info` (or `Line2`) for secondary text

These styles automatically have the correct colors already built in.

For media apps, as such is the one you mention, Notifications should be built with [`NotificationCompat.MediaStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/app/NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.html), which also takes into account the correct background and text colors.

Comment: This should not be suitable for use with custom layouts？

Comment: They're exactly built specifically for custom notification layouts

Comment: Can you give me some examples?

Comment: My notification is just like this:https://github.com/lizixian18/MusicLibrary/blob/master/art/light2.png

Comment: You should be using `MediaStyle` for media notifications.

Comment: hello , I have already solved this problem, but when I use system notification ,I have other  problem :
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343714/how-to-change-notification-background-color-just-like-universal-music-player